# Why should one use str_split() in php?

Tags: php, arrays, string, split

Given the following code :

```
$str = 'CLAX';
echo $str[2];  //prints 'A'
```

then why should I use `str_split( $str )` to convert string to a array of characters ?

I understand `str_split( $str , 2 )` will return array of strings; each string being 2 characters long.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

Comment: In your example there is no need to use `str_split()`.

Comment: You'd use str_split to actually split the string into different parts (and not just access a character) - e.g. splitting a string by a 'space' character to get an array of words

Comment: What and why you want to archive? What have you tried? We aren't in your mind so please try to give us more context to know what you are really asking.

Comment: Its useful if you need to foreach() over the individual characters of a string

Comment: @DCrystal I think you're thinking of explode.  The str_split function can only split into chunks of a specified size.

Answer (score 2):

This function is to split a string into an array with given `string split length`

By default `string split length` is set `1`

If you want to split a string into given in given length, then you can use `str_split`. But in your case you are splitting string with `default length 1` that is by you are getting confused.

```
<?php

$str = "CLAX";
echo $str[2]; //here you are referring to 2 index of string

$arr2 = str_split($str);
Array
(
    [0] => C
    [1] => L
    [2] => A
    [3] => X
)
echo $str[2]; //here you are referring to 2 index of an array
```

[str_split reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

```
<?php

$str = "Hello Friend";
$arr2 = str_split($str, 3);
Array
(
    [0] => Hel
    [1] => lo
    [2] => Fri
    [3] => end
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_split()` comes in pretty handy when you want to leverage array functions to perform a task on the components in a string.

`str_split()` works like `explode()` except it doesn't care what the characters are, just their position in the string -- there are specific use cases for this.

**Use Case #1**: [Group Array Elements by Letter Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371496/group-array-elements-by-letter-range/43372225#43372225)

Rather than manually declaring an array with 3 letters per element, like this:

```
$chunks=['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL','MNO','PQR','STU','VWX','YZ']
```

The same array can be produced with:

```
$chunks=str_split(implode(range('A','Z')),3);
```

This purely for demonstration.  Of course, declaring it manually would be more efficient.  The potential benefit for other cases is code flexibility and ease of code modification.

---

**Use Case #2**: [Convert string to array at different character occurence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991284/convert-string-to-array-at-different-character-occurence/43863774#43863774)

Use `str_split()` when using a foreach loop to process each character.

```
$string="abbbaaaaaabbbb";
$array=str_split($string);
$last="";
foreach($array as $v){
    if(!$last || strpos($last,$v)!==false){
        $last.=$v;
    }else{
        $result[]=$last;
        $last=$v;
    }
}
$result[]=$last;
var_export($result);
```

If you try to supply the foreach loop with `$string` php will choke on it.  `str_split()` is the right tool for this job.

---

**Use Case #3**: [Find element of an array those contains only specific character set in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916223/find-element-of-an-array-those-contains-only-specific-character-set-in-php/43916276#43916276)

Use `str_split()` to in association with other array functions to check values in a way that string functions are not well suited for.

[I'll refrain from transferring the full code block across.]