# Convert string to array at different character occurence

Tags: php, arrays, split, duplicates

Consider I have this string `'aaaabbbaaaaaabbbb'` I want to convert this to array so that I get the following result

```
$array = [
    'aaaa',
    'bbb',
    'aaaaaa',
    'bbbb'   
]
```

How to go about this in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a one-liner using only [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) that generates the expected result with no wasted memory (no array bloat):

Code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qELRo)):

```
$string = 'aaaabbbaaaaaabbbb';
var_export(preg_split('/(.)\1*\K/', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'aaaa',
  1 => 'bbb',
  2 => 'aaaaaa',
  3 => 'bbbb',
)
```

Pattern:

```
(.)         #match any single character
\1*         #match the same character zero or more times
\K          #keep what is matched so far out of the overall regex match
```

The real magic happens with the `\K`, for more reading go [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html).
The `0` parameter in `preg_split()` means "unlimited matches".  This is the default behavior, but it needs to hold its place in the function so that the next parameter is used appropriately as a `flag`
The final parameter is `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` which removes any empty matches.

---

Sahil's [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) method `preg_match_all('/(.)\1{1,}/', $string,$matches);` is a good attempt but it is not perfect for two reasons:

The first issue is that his use of `preg_match_all()` returns two subarrays which is double the necessary result.

The second issue is revealed when `$string="abbbaaaaaabbbb";`.  His method will ignore the first lone character.  Here is its output:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => bbb
            [1] => aaaaaa
            [2] => bbbb
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => b
            [1] => a
            [2] => b
        )
)
```

Sahil's second attempt produces the correct output, but requires much more code.  A more concise non-regex solution could look like this:

```
$array = str_split($string);
$last = "";
foreach ($array as $v) {
    if (!$last || strpos($last, $v) !== false) {
        $last .= $v;
    } else {
        $result[] = $last;
        $last = $v;
    }
}
$result[] = $last;
var_export($result);
```

Answer (score 5):

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/760336)

Regex: `(.)\1{1,}`

`(.)`: Match and capture single character.

`\1`: This will contain first match

`\1{1,}`: Using matched character one or more times.

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$string="aaaabbbaaaaaabbbb";
preg_match_all('/(.)\1{1,}/', $string,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => aaaa
            [1] => bbb
            [2] => aaaaaa
            [3] => bbbb
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => b
        [2] => a
        [3] => b
    )

)
```

**Or:**

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/760342)

```
<?php
$string="aaaabbbaaaaaabbbb";
$array=str_split($string);
$start=0;
$end=  strlen($string);
$indexValue=$array[0];
$result=array();
$resultantArray=array();
while($start!=$end)
{
    if($indexValue==$array[$start])
    {
        $result[]=$array[$start];
    }
    else
    {
        $resultantArray[]=implode("", $result);
        $result=array();

        $result[]=$indexValue=$array[$start];
    }
    $start++;
}
$resultantArray[]=implode("", $result);
print_r($resultantArray);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => aaaa
    [1] => bbb
    [2] => aaaaaa
    [3] => bbbb
)
```